# Makefile CMD long path limit

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, make

When when I have long paths in my project (250+ characters), when I trigger my makefile it can't find the include files.

Is there a way to fix this instead of renaming folders to decrease path length?

Also if my long directory is E:\longpanth\includes and my makefile can't find it. How come if I cd E:\longpanth in CMD it finds the directory correctly, could it be something else than CMD, like make.exe or something?

Note: I'm on windows 10 and I use CMD to trigger my makefile

Comment: [About the \\?\ prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#namespaces): _if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the [MAX_PATH limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation) that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs._

Comment: @JosefZ I tried adding it but still didn't work

Comment: Check if  the file system supports large paths and file names by running following commands from an open cmd: `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -v LongPathsEnabled` and `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects"  -v LongPathsEnabled -S`. BTW, I'd prefer  shortening project paths to a _reasonable_ length:)

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, I tried it but still doesn't work, the point is when I cd E:\longpanth in CMD it finds the directory correctly, could it be something else than CMD, like make.exe or something?